# QGIS 3x problem with rescaling vector (shapefile) layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, scale

I would like to rescale my shapefile layer in a particular location on my map in QGIS.
Unfortunately every time my layer is rescaled in completely different location.

According to this query
[Resizing shapefile features proportionally in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63000/resizing-shapefile-features-proportionally-in-qgis)

I can do it with Affine transformation.

Unfortunately when I run the affine transformation and fill it with my XY coordinates as well as the scale factor I am getting my layer away from my working area.

[image]

[image]

In the X and Y I put the coordinates from Gridreferencefinder.com
In the scale factor I put accordingly 1.3 for X and Y and this is working. The worst thing is the layer itself, which appear at completely different coordinates (bounded black).

I found some solution here:

[Computing parameters for QGIS Affine transformation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/computing-parameters-for-qgis-affine-transformation/127653)

but it looks like it's not the quickest one.

The problem is exactly the same when using SAGA vector transformation and GRASS v.transform.

Is there any way to fix it?
Or possibly can I scale my layer manually using i.e. advanced digitizing toolbar?

Comment: Can you provide an image which shows the distance between you working area and the transformed layer?

Comment: I din't know how to measure distance between layers in QGIS

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273758/enlarge-a-polygon-without-changing-its-shape-or-position, please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A translation moves geometries.

You said you only want to scale them.

So do not enter offsets for a translation.